# How do I use the submit()-function to read out a form and show the content

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I want to use the submit()-function to read out a text from a form-field and display it again. But, upon pressing the submit-button nothing happens. With a diffrent event-handler like keyup() everything works fine. Any suggestions?

```js
$(function() {
    $("#name")
    .on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var namenew = $(this).val();
        $("p.show").html("Hello <strong>" + (namenew) + "</strong>");
    });  
});
```

```html
<section>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <input type="submit" id="submit">
        <p class="show">Hello <strong>Unknown</strong></p>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `submit` event is fired on a form, not an input.

So you need to put a form inside `<section>`, and bind the handler to that. Then you need to use `$("#name").val()` to get the value of the input.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myform")
    .on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var namenew = $("#name").val();
      $("p.show").html("Hello <strong>" + (namenew) + "</strong>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <form id="myform" action="#">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </form>
  <p class="show">Hello <strong>Unknown</strong></p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! The jQuery-API said, that submit() works only with an form-element. My mistake was, that I interpreted the input-element as an form-element. So I need the wrapping form-element.